# Add dictionary key/value to list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following function that is being used to return results for an API. What I want to do is show  `self.ced_url` within `sources` as well. What I'm not understanding is how to add that dictionary key/value into the list comprehension.

```
def to_dict(self):
    ret = {
        "event_data_url": self.ced_url,
        "sources": [s.to_dict() for s in self.sources]
    }
    return ret
```

Comment: Can you add what would be your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Incorporated Kaya's suggestion to use `ret['sources'].append(self.ced_url)`

Assuming you want `ced_url` as part of `sources` in `ret`:

```
def to_dict(self):
    ret = {
        "event_data_url": self.ced_url,
        "sources": [s.to_dict() for s in self.sources]
    }
    ret['sources'].append(self.ced_url)
    return ret
```

Comment: `ret['sources'].append(self.ced_url)` would be simpler.